# Spring boot custom query MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I have this MongoDb query:

```
db.getCollection('user').find({
    $and : [
        {"status" : "ACTIVE"},
        {"last_modified" : { $lt: new Date(), $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))}},
        {"$expr": { "$ne": ["$last_modified", "$time_created"] }}
    ]
})
```

It works in Robo3T, but when I put this in spring boot as custom query, it throws error on project start.

```
@Query("{ $and : [ {'status' : 'ACTIVE'}, {'last_modified' : { $lt: new Date(), $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))}}, {'$expr': { '$ne': ['$last_modified', '$time_created']}}]}")
    public List<User> findModifiedUsers();
```

I tried to make query with `Criteria` in spring:

```
Query query = new Query();
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();  
criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("status").is(UserStatus.ACTIVE), Criteria.where("last_modified").lt(new Date()).gt(lastDay), Criteria.where("time_created").ne("last_modified"));
```

but it doesn't work, it returns me all users like there is no this last criteria not equal `last_modified` and `time_created`.

Does anyone know what could be problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this feature is not supported yet by Criteria - check this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1845 . 
One workaround is to pass raw query via mongoTemplate like this:

```
BasicDBList expr = new BasicDBList();
expr.addAll(Arrays.asList("$last_modified","$time_created")); 

BasicDBList and = new BasicDBList();
and.add(new BasicDBObject("status","ACTIVE"));
and.add(new BasicDBObject("last_modified",new BasicDBObject("$lt",new Date()).append("$gte",lastDate)));
and.add(new BasicDBObject("$expr",new BasicDBObject("$ne",expr)));

Document document = new Document("$and",and); 
FindIterable<Document> result = mongoTemplate.getCollection("Users").find(document);
```

Comment: I edited my answer, just create new variable with the expression

Comment: still doesn't work http://prntscr.com/mkpsvc, http://prntscr.com/mkpt6c, http://prntscr.com/mkptcr